# Installer runs and fails at startup

Tags: windows-7, windows, installer, windows-installer

Whenever I reboot my Windows 7 computer, the systems tries to install an update to HP Photosmart Essentials. This window pops up:

[image]

After a few seconds, it is replaced by this:

[image]

If I press "OK", the first box reappears and the process repeats itself. I have to press "Cancel" 4-6 times for the thing to stop.

I've looked through the programs executed at startup, but I'm unsure about what program actually initiates the installation.

I don't use HP Photosmart Essential, so I will be perfectly happy to uninstall the program; but the problem is that I'm unsure if uninstalling might only make matters worse.

Can anybody give me some guidance as to what would be the wise thing to do?

**EDIT:**

Here's a list of my statup programs (generated by CCleaner):

```
GarminExpressTrayApp            Garmin Ltd or its subsidiaries  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Garmin\Express Tray\ExpressTray.exe"
GoogleDriveSync                 Google                          "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe" /autostart
RESTART_STICKY_NOTES            Microsoft Corporation           C:\WINDOWS\System32\StikyNot.exe
Sidebar                         Microsoft Corporation           C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\sidebar.exe /autoRun
Skype                           Skype Technologies S.A.         "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /minimized /regrun
Adobe ARM                       Adobe Systems Incorporated      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARM.exe"
Adobe Reader Speed Launcher     Adobe Systems Incorporated      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\Reader_sl.exe"
APSDaemon                       Apple Inc.                      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Apple Application Support\APSDaemon.exe"
avast                           AVAST Software                  "C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\avastUI.exe" /nogui
Broadcom Wireless Manager UI    Dell Inc.                       C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Wireless WLAN Card\WLTRAY.exe
CanonSolutionMenu               CANON INC.                      C:\Program Files (x86)\Canon\SolutionMenu\CNSLMAIN.exe /logon
Dell Webcam Central             Creative Technology Ltd         "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell Webcam\Dell Webcam Central\WebcamDell2.exe" /mode2
Desktop Disc Tool               Sonic Solutions                 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\Roxio Burn\RoxioBurnLauncher.exe"
DivXUpdate                      DivX, LLC                       "C:\Program Files (x86)\DivX\DivX Update\DivXUpdate.exe" /CHECKNOW
HP Software Update              Hewlett-Packard                 C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\HP Software Update\HPWuSchd2.exe
iTunesHelper                    Apple Inc.                      "C:\Program Files (x86)\iTunes\iTunesHelper.exe"
Mobile Connectivity Suite       Teleca Sweden AB                "C:\Program Files (x86)\HTC\HTC Sync\Application Launcher\Application Launcher.exe" /startoptions
OpwareSE4                       Nuance Communications, Inc.     "C:\Program Files (x86)\ScanSoft\OmniPageSE4\OpwareSE4.exe"
PDVDDXSrv                       CyberLink Corp.                 "C:\Program Files (x86)\CyberLink\PowerDVD DX\PDVDDXSrv.exe"
QuickSet                        Dell Inc.                       C:\Program Files\Dell\QuickSet\QuickSet.exe
QuickTime Task                  Apple Inc.                      "C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTTask.exe" -atboottime
SSBkgdUpdate                    Nuance Communications, Inc.     "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Scansoft Shared\SSBkgdUpdate\SSBkgdupdate.exe" -Embedding -boot
StartCCC                        Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.    "c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\CLIStart.exe" MSRun
SunJavaUpdateSched              Sun Microsystems, Inc.          "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Java\Java Update\jusched.exe"
SynTPEnh                        Synaptics Incorporated          %ProgramFiles%\Synaptics\SynTP\SynTPEnh.exe
SysTrayApp                      IDT, Inc.                       C:\Program Files\IDT\WDM\sttray64.exe
VirtualCloneDrive               Elaborate Bytes AG              "C:\Program Files (x86)\Elaborate Bytes\VirtualCloneDrive\VCDDaemon.exe" /s
VMware hqtray                   VMware, Inc.                    "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\hqtray.exe"
Windows Mobile Device Center    Microsoft Corporation           %windir%\WindowsMobile\wmdc.exe
WrtMon.exe                                                      C:\Windows\system32\spool\drivers\x64\3\WrtMon.exe
DSUpdateLauncher                Dell                            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell DataSafe Local Backup\Components\DSUpdate\hstart.exe"
Launcher                        Softthinks                      C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell DataSafe Local Backup\Components\scheduler\Launcher.exe
STToasterLauncher               Dell Inc.                       C:\program files (x86)\Dell DataSafe Local Backup\toasterLauncher.exe
Bluetooth.lnk                   Broadcom Corporation.           C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\BTTray.exe
Google Calendar Sync.lnk        Google                          C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Calendar Sync\GoogleCalendarSync.exe
HP Digital Imaging Monitor.lnk  Hewlett-Packard Co.             C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Digital Imaging\bin\hpqtra08.exe
MozyHome Status.lnk             Mozy, Inc.                      C:\Program Files\MozyHome\mozystat.exe
Dropbox.lnk                     Dropbox, Inc.                   C:\Users\Claus\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\bin\Dropbox.exe
EvernoteClipper.lnk             Evernote Corp.                  C:\Program Files (x86)\Evernote\Evernote\EvernoteClipper.exe
```

Comment: What are your list of startup programs? If they're not many, you can paste it here. Also check your list of services

Comment: I've added the startup list to my post. (Note: "HP Software Update" is not the culprit -- see my comments elsewhere.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you download either TuneUp Utilities
http://www.tune-up.com/products/tuneup-utilities/features/

or CCleaner
http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner

and let them perform a system cleanup, startup cleanup and registry cleanup. ( The exact procedure to do these differ in both the applications but are pretty self explanatory).

After that you should try looking one by one into Startup applications in CCleaner/TuneUp. Try reading through the descriptions or recognizing them by name or location of the services. Disable the ones you do not need.

## **UPDATE -**

Here's what worked for @oz1cz :

He downloaded and started the installer for Photosmart Essential program again. And the rest as quoted by him :

> It said, "Photosmart Essential is already installed, do you want to
>   uninstall it?" At this point I threw caution to the wind and answered,
>   "Yes". After a rebook my problem was gone! The funny thing is that
>   Photosmart Essential has not been unistalled, but the system doesn't
>   try to reinstall it anymore.

Comment: I've tried CCleaner. It analysis revealed nothing, and there's nothing in the startup list that looks like it might be related to my problem (except "HP Software Update" which I have mentioned in another comment, and which is not the cause of the problem).

Comment: This is another duct tape method but will work for sure:

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-All-in-One-Install-Setup-e-g-Windows-8/HP-Photosmart-Essential-msi-is-missing/m-p/539735#M27168

Comment: Anurag, I tried your "duct tape" method. I downloaded the Photosmart Essential program and ran it. It said, "Photosmart Essential is already installed, do you want to uninstall it?" At this point I threw caution to the wind and answered, "Yes". After a rebook my problem was gone! The funny thing is that Photosmart Essential has not been unistalled, but the system doesn't try to reinstall it anymore. Anurag, if you turn you comment into an answer, I will acknowledge it as a solution. Thank you.

Comment: @oz1cz I have edited my previous answer to include what worked for you. Please accept if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `msconfig`. Then go to `startup` tab and find `HP Photosmart Essentials Update` or something like that. Then uncheck it. It doesn't bother you again.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Kind of like putting duct tape over the Check Engine light :).

Comment: There is no entry with a name that looks remotely like "HP Photosmart Essentials Update". The closest entry is "HP Software Update" with the file name "C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\HP Software Update\HPWuSchd2.exe". I tried disabling that, but it had no effect on my problem.

Comment: @oz1cz When it comes up you can check from Process Manager where it is stored.

Comment: @BradPatton yes you are right, but I don't have the computer in front of me to diagnose the problem.